# iTunes is not recognising my iPhone after upgrading to Lion

Tags: iphone, macos, itunes

I've just upgraded my Mac to Lion, and now my iPhone is not being recognised in iTunes.

I've tried...

- Updating iTunes (to 10.5)
- Checking for all updates
- Restarting both the Mac and iPhone
- Extracting iTunesHelper.app from the iTunes bundle and installing it into the Login Items list, and confirmed it's running in the Activity Monitor.

For the past 3 years I've been happy with the "It just works" idea, but not today. :(

What other options are there?

Comment: Does the phone's screen light up when you connect it? Does it charge when connected to the computer? Have you tried another cable?

Comment: @Jannemans - Yes the phone lights up and charges ok.

Comment: SOLVED: Out of desperation I downloaded and installed iTunes a second time, and now the phone is detected! Don't understand why the first update to 10.5 didn't do the trick.

Comment: @Bill you should mark your question as answered since the problem is resolved :-)

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking in the system profiler under USB to see if the Mac see's that the iPhone is connected.
.

[image: System Profiler]

Then remove the following to the Trash and RESTART the computer

/System/Library/Extensions and Locate the file **AppleMobileDevice.kext**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to try these, as I found a second install of iTunes ended up solving the problem. It will be handy having this post here for the future though, in case I encounter the problem again.